# Stop repeating animation - CSS, JS

Tags: javascript

I have text animated in JavaScript and CSS but the problem is that text is repeated constantly. How I can stop repeating after is shown once and stay displayed.

Javascript code is:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.2/anime.min.js"></script>
<script>
    // Wrap every letter in a span
    var textWrapper = document.querySelector('.slogan');
    textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/\S/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>");

    anime.timeline({loop: true})
    .add({
        targets: '.slogan .letter',
        opacity: [0,1],
        easing: "easeInOutQuad",
        duration: 2250,
        delay: (el, i) => 150 * (i+1)
    }).add({
        targets: '.slogan',
        opacity: 0,
        duration: 1000,
        easing: "easeOutExpo",
        delay: 1000
    });
</script>
```

The final result that I need is an after-show slogan to stay like that till customers refresh the page and stop repeating after 1 time.

Thanks all

Comment: Try replacing `loop: true` with `loop: false` ! ;)

Comment: With ```loop: false``` it was displayed once but then hidden, i don't want to hide I want to stay @Programmer

Comment: I found the solution. I need to remove the addition add segment in javascript code that hides after 1s. @Programmer